# Alternatives for PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE or PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy as it is deprecated now

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

In prior versions of jackson, we were using the following two ways to modify the Property Naming during serialization and deserialization of objects.

**First way**:
Mentioning the following annotation on class level.

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

**Second way**:
Setting the PropertyNamingStrategy in Object Mapper itself.

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class);

or,

objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Now as it has been deprecated from version 2.13.

**Reference** : https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2715

Now what are the alternative for the above thing.

Could anyone please help me with how it can be done?

Was trying the above two ways, but its is showing deprecated now.

Comment: Deprecated are only the constants like SNAKE_CASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTE! Since 2.12 sub-classes defined here (as well as static singleton instances thereof) are deprecated due to databind#2715. Please use constants and classes in PropertyNamingStrategies instead.

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategies.html

Answer (score 18):

Old:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
```

To New:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
-- or 
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is easy to overlook is that the base class is another class (PropertyNamingStrateg***ies***)

Answer (score 8):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy());
```

That's it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).